# How add an image in folder

Tags: java

I created a folder (`C:/test`) :

```
File dir = new File("C:/test");     
dir.mkdirs();
```

I want to add an image in this folder. The image is in project folder `/resources/1.png`.

```
try {
    FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("1.png");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
    fin.read(buffer, 0, fin.available());
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C://Dir//1.png");
    fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 
} catch(IOException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Read bytes from `/resources/1.png`, and put them into output stream which will point to `C:/test/1.png`. Update your question when you will have more specific problem.

Comment: If you have more informations use [edit] option and place them in your question, don't post them as comment (not everyone reads comments, and comments don't support proper code formatting).

Comment: Where is your `resources` folder located? Is it part of your project? Is it inside JAR file which will be created from your project?

Comment: I created  maven project . And resources folder located  in webapp

Comment: You should check out the [ImageIO javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in Java [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)?

```
try {
   File input = new File("resources/1.png");  // your input file
   File output = new File("C://test/1.png");  // your output file
   BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(in);  
   ImageIO.write(bi, "png", out);  // rendered image, file type, file
}catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.